# Proof of an inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

If I am given that $$0<\lambda_2<d_0<\lambda_1$$ and would like to prove that $$c_1e^{-\lambda_1(T-t)}+c_2e^{-\lambda_2(T-t)}>e^{-d_0(T-t)},$$ where $$c_1=\frac{\lambda_2-d_0}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}\;c_2=\frac{\lambda_1-d_0}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2},$$ how should I proceed ? I think its just algebraic simplification but I dont seem to get anyway. I can see that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive.

Comment: $c_1$ and $c_2$ are such that $c_1 \in (0,1)$ and $c_2\in (0,1)$ and $c_1+c_2=1$, it smells convexity here...Please look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f(x)=e^{-x(T-t)}$.

Consider the points $P_1(\lambda_1,f(\lambda_1))$ and $P_2(\lambda_2,f(\lambda_2))$. Now, using [Lagrange Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) between these points we estimate that

$$\begin{align}
f(d_0)&\approx \frac{d_0-\lambda_1}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}f(\lambda_2)+\frac{d_0-\lambda_2}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}f(\lambda_1)
\\&=c_2f(\lambda_2)+c_1f(\lambda_1)
\\&=c_1f(\lambda_1)+c_2f(\lambda_2)
\end{align}
$$

Now $f(x)=e^{-x(T-t)}$ is convex as $f''(x)=(T-t)^2e^{-x(T-t)}>0$, so that the linear interpolation estimate will always lie above the curve.

Therefore the approximation is an overestimate and so

$$c_1f(\lambda_1)+c_2f(\lambda_2)>f(d_0).$$